# How to read and write files and process files using file-descriptor or system call in c using struct with index

Tags: c, struct, file-descriptor

I'm writing an application in c using file descriptor, open, read, write to store information to a file using a struct array with content `{name,age,mob}` eg 
`struct Students student[50]`. How do i handle the read back to the struct and say retrieve other information of the student by the name like a search..?
Help is Appreciated

This what i tried so far but still not working as expected

```
// functions to implement
short studentInDatabase;
void saveStudentToFile();
void requireEntered();
void addStudent();
void showStudents();
void loadStudentFromFile();
void searchDatabase();
struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char age[20]; //using char array because i can't save int to file
    char telephone[20];

};

struct Student newStudent[500];
struct Student myUserInfo;
```

```
void addStudent()
{

    printf("Type Student Name: ");
    scanf("%s",  myUserInfo.name );

    printf("Type Surname: ");
    scanf("%s", myUserInfo.surname);

    printf("Type Age: ");
    scanf("%s", myUserInfo.age);

    printf("Type Telephone: ");
    scanf("%s", myUserInfo.telephone);

    studentInDatabase++;

}
```

```
void showStudents()
{
    if(peopleInDatabase > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < peopleInDatabase; i++)
        {
            printf("Person in index %d\n", i+1);
            printf("Name: %s \n", myUserInfo.name);
            printf("Surname: %s\n",myUserInfo.surname );
            printf("Age: %s\n",myUserInfo.age);
            printf("Telephone: %s\n\n",myUserInfo.telephone);
// Use this is using the newStudents Array structure
//            printf("Person in index %d\n", i+1);
//            printf("Name: %s \n", newStudents [i].name);
//            printf("Surname: %s\n", newStudents [i].surname );
//            printf("Age: %s\n", newStudents [i].age);
//            printf("Telephone: %s\n\n", newStudents [i].telephone);

        }
    }
    else {
          printf("There is nobody available...");
    }
}
```

```
void savePeopleToFile()
{
    //char *mega_string;
    int  fd, ret, sz, ssz, asz, tsz, psz, fdd;
    char fn[]="writefile.txt";

    fd = open(fn, O_WRONLY| O_CREAT| O_APPEND );
    if(fd < 0 )
    {
        perror("open write() error");
        printf("Error Creating File\n");
    }

    printf("Open File Successfully......%d\n\n", fd);

    if(peopleInDatabase > 0)
    {
//        printf("People in Database......%d\n", psz);
        for(int i = 0; i < peopleInDatabase; i++)
        {
            //
            sz = write(fd, myUserInfo.name , sizeof( myUserInfo.name));
            printf("Size for name......%d\n", sz);

            ssz = write(fd, myUserInfo.surname, sizeof(myUserInfo.surname));
            printf("Size for Surname......%d\n", ssz);

            asz = write(fd, myUserInfo.age, sizeof(myUserInfo.age));
            printf("Size for age......%d\n", asz);

            tsz = write(fd, myUserInfo.telephone, sizeof(myUserInfo.telephone));
            printf("Size for telephone......%d\n", tsz);
        }
//
//            sz = write(fd, newStudents [i].name, sizeof(people[i].name));
//            printf("Size for name......%d\n", sz);
//
//            ssz = write(fd, newStudents[i].surname, sizeof(people[i].surname));
//            printf("Size for Surname......%d\n", ssz);
//
//            asz = write(fd, newStudents [i].age, sizeof(people[i].age));
//            printf("Size for age......%d\n", asz);
//
//            tsz = write(fd, newStudents[i].telephone, sizeof(people[i].telephone));
//            printf("Size for telephone......%d\n", tsz);
        }
    close(fd);
}
```

```
void loadStudentFromFile()
{
    int readret, someSize;
    int foo;
    int  fd;
    char buf[4096];
    char fn[]="writefile.txt";
     if((fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY )) < 0)
    {
        perror("creat() error");
        printf("Error Creating File\n");
    }

    // Use this when using array structure
    readret = read(fd, newStudent , sizeof(newStudent) != EOF);

    // Use this when using myUserInfo structure
    readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(myUserInfo) != EOF);

    while (readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(people) != EOF))
    {
           printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
           printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
           printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
           printf("Age: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.age);
           printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",  myUserInfo.telephone);
    };

// Check for readret in not -1 or EOF
//    if(readret > 0)
//    {
//        int i = 0;
//        for(; i < 10; i++)
//        {
////             printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
////             printf("Name: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].name);
//               printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
//               printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
////             printf("Age: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].age);
////             printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",   newStudent[i].telephone);
//
//             if(newStudent[i].surname == "Midel" )
//             {
//                 printf("%s %s is Available ....\n",myUserInfo.name, myUserInfo.surname);
//             }
//      }
//   }

    close(fd);
}
```

```
void searchDatabase(char search[])
{
    int readret, someSize;
    int foo;
    int  fd;
    char buf[4096];
    char fn[]="writefile.txt";
     if((fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY )) < 0)
    {
        perror("creat() error");
        printf("Error Creating File\n");
    }

    // Use this when using array structure
    readret = read(fd, newStudent , sizeof(newStudent) != EOF);

    // Use this when using myUserInfo structure
    readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(myUserInfo) != EOF);

    while (readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(people) != EOF))
    {
         if(newStudent[i].surname == "search" )
//        {
//           Return Details of User when Found....  
//            printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
//           printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
//           printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
//           printf("Age: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.age);
//           printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",  myUserInfo.telephone);
//        }

    };

// Check for readret in not -1 or EOF
//    if(readret > 0)
//    {
//        int i = 0;
//        for(; i < 10; i++)
//        {
////             printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
////             printf("Name: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].name);
//               printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
//               printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
////             printf("Age: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].age);
////             printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",   newStudent[i].telephone);
//
//             if(&people[i].surname == "search" )
//             {
//                 printf("%s %s is Available ....\n",myUserInfo.name, myUserInfo.surname);
//             }
//      }
//   }

    close(fd);
}
```

I was expecting to get the number of students in DB File when am reading

```
// Write four (4) students or people
if(peopleInDatabase < 4)
    {
//        printf("People in Database......%d\n", psz);
        for(int i = 0; i < peopleInDatabase; i++)
        {
            //
            sz = write(fd, myUserInfo.name , sizeof( myUserInfo.name));
            printf("Size for name......%d\n", sz);

            ssz = write(fd, myUserInfo.surname, sizeof(myUserInfo.surname));
            printf("Size for Surname......%d\n", ssz);

            asz = write(fd, myUserInfo.age, sizeof(myUserInfo.age));
            printf("Size for age......%d\n", asz);

            tsz = write(fd, myUserInfo.telephone, sizeof(myUserInfo.telephone));
            printf("Size for telephone......%d\n", tsz);
        }
```

```
// Use this when using array structure should return 4 
// i.e Shouldn't exceed 4
    readret = read(fd, newStudent , sizeof(newStudent) != EOF);

    // Use this when using myUserInfo structure
    readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(myUserInfo) != EOF);

    while (readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(people) != EOF))
    {
           printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
           printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
           printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
           printf("Age: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.age);
           printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",  myUserInfo.telephone);
    };
```

```
void searchStudent(char search[])
// Check for readret in not -1 or EOF
//    if(readret > 0)
//    {
//        int i = 0;
//        for(; i < 10; i++)
//        {
//             if(newStudent[i].surname == "search" )
//             {
//                 printf("%s %s is Available ....\n",myUserInfo.name, myUserInfo.surname);
//                  printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
////             printf("Name: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].name);
//               printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
//               printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
////             printf("Age: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].age);
////             printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",   newStudent[i].telephone);
//             }
//      }
//   }
```

Currently it doesn't work... Loop falls through

```
int main()
{
    char test;
    loadPeopleFromFile();

    do
    {
        printf( "Number of People In Database... %d \n", peopleInDatabase);
        printf( "MENU\n");

        printf("1. Add Student\n");
        printf( "2. Show All Students\n");
        printf("3. Save Student to database... \n");
        printf( "4. Load Students from file/db...\n");
        printf( "5. Search Student from file/db database\n");
        printf( "6. Remove Student from file/db database..\n");


        test = getchar();

        switch(test)
        {
        case '1':
            addPerson();
            break;
        case '2':
             showPeople();
             break;
        case '3':
            savePeopleToFile();
            break;
        case '4':
            loadPeopleFromFile();
            break;
        case '5':
            searchDatabase();
            break;
        case '6':
            removePersonFromDatabase();
            break;
        }

        requireEntered();
        system("cls");
    } while(test != 27);

    return 0;
}
void requireEntered()
{
        printf("Click enter to continue.....");
        while(getch() != 13);
}
```

This is the implementation in main.... as requested..
If i mean fall through... I can get the actual number of records i saved unless i add initialize and int bigger for the loop.. Say i save 5 records.. i write

```
readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(myUserInfo));
if(readret > 0)
   {
       int i = 0;
       for(; i < 10; i++)
       {
             printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
             printf("Name: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].name);
             printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
             printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
             printf("Age: %s  \n",   newStudent[i].age);
             printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",   newStudent[i].telephone);

            if(newStudent[i].surname == "Midel" )
            {
                printf("%s %s is Available ....\n",myUserInfo.name, myUserInfo.surname);
            }
        }
     }

//NB I only use 
readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo, sizeof(myUserInfo) != EOF); //for the while loop
 while (readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(people) != EOF))
    {
           printf("Person Index: %d \n", (i+1));
           printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
           printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
           printf("Age: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.age);
           printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",  myUserInfo.telephone);
    };
```

Any help on getting the exact number of what i save so i can use for loop is appreciated thanks...
Say i retrieve that an pass to `int studentsInDb` then i can `if i < studentsInDb`.. Thanks

Comment: Apart from errors mentioned in Paul Ogilvie's answer, it is difficult to understand when you call which piece of code and what are the preconditions. There are even syntax errors in your code. You don't show how you call your functions. Maybe this is in the `main` function? Please [edit] your question and add more details and what exactly you mean with "Loop falls through". Which loop? Comparing the result of `read()` with `EOF` is probably wrong. `read()` will return the number of bytes it has read, which may be less than you want, or `0` on EOF or `<0` on error.

Comment: @Bodo ... Thanks for view.... I have edited and added for explanations sure it is clear for your aid... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains several problems.

**This answer addresses the saving and loading of the data only.**

I assume the number of records is small enough to read the all data to an array in memory and do all operations like adding/searching/removing records in memory using this array. Of course after any modification the data must be written back to the file. Because of this approach, the file is opened  for writing with `O_TRUNC`, not with `O_APPEND`.

(It would be possible to work directly on the file, but such a solution will be more difficult to implement. Appending records to the existing data in the file is easy, searching while reading the data from the file is also no problem, but deleting records from the file would be difficult. You either would have to mark a record as deleted or move all data following the deleted record. Moving data inside a file will be difficult.)

I assume that `studentInDatabase` is initialized with 0 and incremented by `addStudent()` for every new record.

This means you should use

```
short studentInDatabase = 0;
```

In `savePeopleToFile()` I suggest to write whole structures instead of individual fields. Note that writing binary data is platform specific.

```
void savePeopleToFile()
{
    int  fd, sz, i;

    fd = open(fn, O_WRONLY| O_CREAT | O_TRUNC ); /* not O_APPEND because we want to overwrite the file */
    if(fd < 0 )
    {
        perror("open write() error");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Creating File\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Open File Successfully......%d\n\n", fd);

//        printf("People in Database......%d\n", psz);
    /* you could write the number of persons to the file if you want to have a cross-check */
    for(int i = 0; i < peopleInDatabase; i++)
    {

        sz = write(fd, &newStudent[i] , sizeof(newStudent[0]));

        /* TODO error handling if sz < 0 or handling of partial write if sz != sizeof(newStudent[0]) */

        printf("Size for person......%d\n", sz);

    }
    if(close(fd) < 0)
    {
        perror("close() error");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Closing File\n");
    }
}
```

Note: This code is untested.

When reading the data you have two options. If you have written the number of persons to the file, you can read this number first, then use a `for` loop. Otherwise use a `while` loop reading one record per cycle until EOF and count the number of records.

Solution using a while loop:

```
void loadStudentFromFile()
{
    int readret;
    int  fd;

    if((fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY )) < 0)
    {
        perror("open() error");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Opening File\n");
        return;
    }

    peopleInDatabase = 0;

    do
    {
        /* you could read directly to newStudent[peopleInDatabase], but I use
           myUserInfo for easier access to the fields for printing */
        readret = read(fd, &myUserInfo , sizeof(myUserInfo));

        /* TODO handle errors and partial reads */

        if(readret > 0)
        {
            printf("Person Index: %d \n", peopleInDatabase);
            printf("Name: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.name);
            printf("Surname: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.surname);
            printf("Age: %s  \n",   myUserInfo.age);
            printf("Tel: %s  \n\n",  myUserInfo.telephone);

            newStudent[peopleInDatabase] = myUserInfo;
            peopleInDatabase++
        }
    } while(readret > 0);

    /* readret == 0 means EOF */
    if(readret < 0)
    {
        perror("read() error");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Reading File\n");
    }

    if(close(fd) < 0)
    {
        perror("close() error");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Closing File\n");
    }
}
```

Note: This code is untested.

**Remarks about search and remove functions**

The menu entries `5. Search Student from file/db database` and `6. Remove Student from file/db database..` are not clear to me, specifically the term "from file".

If you have loaded the file into memory using `4. Load Students from file/db...` you can do the operations for 5 and 6 in memory by accessing your array of data structures and after modifications save the data to the file using `3. Save Student to database...`.

Or are you supposed to automatically read/write the file for 5 and 6?

Comment: ok.... I will testing the above suggestion right away and also i found out i do have access to any data i read from file to the struct outside while loop... Sure the above suggestion may help.. Will let know what ever come up...

Comment: `loadStudentFromFile()` is working just fine....
Concerning the **Remarks about search and remove functions**
is to pass a search parameter to the function, load and loop through the data from file/db if found, return the details the student or update a specific field and save back
`
void searchByAny(char studentParam[])
{
   if((strcmp(myUserInfo.name, studentParam) || (strcmp(myUserInfo.telephone, studentParam)) == 0 )
return foundStudent;
break: // Same for delete if found delete the matched record of student

}
`

Comment: @Bolo ref:  specifically the term "from file" am only writing everything to file, also i use the `O_APPEND` because i want to add to what already written to file without removing the rest... if i should use the `O_TRUNC ` how do i achieve same result without loading contents from the file before writing...

Comment: Had and error on this `void savePeopleToFile()`  ` sz = write(fd, newStudent[i], sizeof(newStudent[0]))`
Error `error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'write'`

Comment: With the earlier approach i later had permission issues which wasn't so `open write() error: Permission denied` Will be glad for any suggestions...

Comment: @Avalon regarding the error about incompatible type: I forgot an `&`-> `sz = write(fd, &newStudent[i], sizeof(newStudent[0]))`. Regarding overwriting or appending to the file: Please describe the use case. What should be in the file, what will be added. Appending new entries is be easy, but deleting entries will be difficult if you want to do all manipulations with reading/writing the file.

Comment: regarding the file manipulation... I want to add new entries to the existing ones / modify... I think one scenario might work for the other or what do you think.. cos i load the entries before doing further processing like adding... So i add up to the existing index .... Whats your suggestions...

Comment: With a limited number of entries I suggest to read the whole file into memory, do all changes in memory and write the whole data back to the file.

Comment: @Avalon If this is not what you want, you should describe your use cases in your question. How is the user of your program supposed to use the menu options 1..6. Can (s)he use 1, 2, 5, 6 without using 4 before? What exactly do you want to happen on various combinations of the menu options? Should the data be added/modified/deleted in a data structure in memory and/or in the file? How many records should your program be able to handle?

Answer (score 2):

Your add function reads into a single student record, but never updates the student array. You should use an index of the number of students in the array and read directly into the next free element:

```
struct Student newStudent[500];
int studentInDatabase;
```

and now read like:

```
    printf("Type Student Name: ");
    scanf("%s",  newStudent[studentInDatabase].name );
    //...
    studentInDatabase++;
```

The same for `showStudents`, where the commented-out code seems correct. Etcetera, for all your other functions.

Note: `if(newStudent[i].surname == "search" )`: use `strcmp()` to compare strings, so `if (strcmp(newStudent[i].surname, "search")==0 )`

Comment: To add a new user you could also use `newStudent[studentInDatabase] = myUserInfo; studentInDatabase++;`

Comment: @Paul Ogilivie .. I trying it out now... Please will let know how far about the come... Thanks

Comment: @Bodo Thanks but how about the error am facing when re-writing the data back to file after adding a new recode `open write() error: Permission denied` 
Am using `fd = open(fn, O_WRONLY| O_CREAT | O_TRUNC )`